# How to retrive POST data from html page in Node.js using connect module

Tags: node.js, post

I have following HTML Form code..

```
<div id="contact_form">    
     <form method="post" name="contact" action="localhost:8080">
     <label for="author">Name:</label> <input name="author" type="text" class="input_field" id="author"/>
     <label for="email">Email:</label> <input name="email" type="text" class="input_field" id="email"/>
     <label for="text">Message:</label> <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea>
     <input type="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
     </form>
</div>
```

And My Node.js Server code is as follows

```
var connect = require('connect');
var server = connect.createServer(
   connect.static(__dirname)
).listen(8080);
```

I want to retrieve the POST method values from HTML form in Node.js.. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're server code is missing a lot, namely anything about actual url-handling, so I'd start with checking out [express](http://expressjs.com/guide.html), which is just connect made sensible.  You're going to end up with something like:

```
express = require("express")
app = express()
app.post("URL_HERE", function(req, res) {
    // HANDLE POST
    data = req.body
    // DO STUFF WITH THE DATA
})
app.listen(8080)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var http =  require('http');
var connect = require('connect');

var app = connect()
  .use(connect.bodyParser())
  .use(connect.static(__dirname))
  .use(function(req, res){
    console.log('email:'+req.body.email);
  })

http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
```